# add function for class dynamically without jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have arrow with class `detail` and after click event I add class 'close'.

How can I set function for this arrow with `close` class?

```
var arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow-down.detail');
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('div.img');
for (i = 0; i < imgs.len; i++) {
    imgs[i].onclick = function(e) {
        this.classList.add('active');
        arrow.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg)';
        arrow.style.color = '#000';
        arrow.style.borderColor = '#000';
        arrow.classList.add('close');
    }
};
```

I need something like this:

```
$('.detail.close').click(function(){
})
```

Comment: it is not clear what you need.

Comment: i need to set function for arrow with `close` which close `img` block.

Comment: actually, i forgot to write `this.classList.add('active')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You make code like below, it will listen on body element to all click events, but will call callback it it comes from '.detail.close' only 'body' has to exist when below code is fired. It will solve Your problem.

```
$('body').on('click', '.detail.close', function(){
    // do sth
});
```

Happy hacking and happy holidays!